# How to hide/show table columns based on row cell values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table class="mytbl">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-1</th>  <----these actually are timestamps.
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-2</th>
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-3</th>
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-4</th>
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-5</th>
    <th>dyn-tbl-hdr-6</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>20</td>
   <td>50</td>
   <td>60</td>
   <td>20</td>
   <td>50</td>
   <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>33</td>
   <td>5455</td>
   <td>4550</td>
   <td>245</td>
   <td>50566</td>
   <td>5678</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>33433</td>
   <td>598455</td>
   <td>894550</td>
   <td>96245</td>
   <td>7050566</td>
   <td>4325678</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to display only those "columns" whose value in first row is 20 (or 20 and 60). I want to show/hide columns based on any row's cell value. objective is to show only those columns for which value of cell in a given row matches. (So in above example show only those columns for which the row 1 contains 20 (If user want to see 20). Can I show only those columns for which ro1 contains 20 and 50? I guess I need to first pick a row, then cell values, then hide columns based on that row and selected cell values. But I am not sure how to code this in jquery. I appreciate all help.

In my app table is dynamically generated. Table headers are not constant they are actually timestamps.

Comment: What type of event should call the filter function? Click, Page load, change, blur, focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var col = new Array();
$('tr').eq('1').find('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 20 || $(this).text() == 50) {
        col.push($(this).index());
    }

});
$('th,td').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).index(), col)==-1) $(this).hide();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r73nB/1/)**

This searches the table's first non-header row for values of 20 or 50 and hides the columns that don't have those values.

Comment: i like this best, it does exactly what i wanted to do. thanks a lot!! i was thinking to move to jqgrid, but i am good with this.

Comment: This is in continuation of this Question: "how to hide/show table columns based on row cell values?"

Now that it has been achieved, a new problem has come up. some tables have very large number of columns. (say around 12000 columns). On systems which have enough RAM table is being displayed correctly, but hiding column operation is taking very long time (almost failing), getting the dialog box 'script taking long time... jquery...'.

how can i make it faster?

ty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.each` function from jQuery to handle this.

**Reference**: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

**jQuery**:

```
$("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() != 20) {
        $(this).css("opacity", "0");
    }
});​
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/d2arY/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mytbl tbody tr:first td').map(function(index, el) {

    if ($(el).text() == 60) 

             return $(el).index();  // get index of td that contain 60

}).each(function(i, val) {  // loop over those index

    $('.mytbl tbody td, .mytbl thead th').each(function() {

        $(this).parent().find('td, th').eq(val).hide(); // hide th and td with
                                                        // similar index
    });
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/608/)**